# Create Microsoft Outlook calendar invite from Microsoft Teams meeting link

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-teams

Is it possible to create a calendar event for Microsoft Outlook from the link for a Microsoft Teams meeting? For example, if I receive an email with information about joining a meeting (meeting time, link, meeting ID, password, etc.) but no calendar invite, can I use the meeting information to generate an event?

*Edit*: I should be specific that I am asking if it is possible to do this without manually creating a new event and keeping the meeting info in the notes. I sometimes make mistakes with time zones when I do this (my problem, I understand) and was wondering if there was an alternative.

Comment: You can create an appointment and add the link in the notes. That works.

Comment: That is my current approach and mostly works. However, I updated the question to be more specific and indicate that I was wondering if it was possible to do this without manually creating an event.

Comment: I do not think there is an automatic way to create an event without an invite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am asking if it is possible to do this without manually creating a
> new event and keeping the meeting info in the notes.

This is not possible based on my wide experience with Outlook.

The usual workaround is to create an appointment, add the Meeting Link in the Notes area of the appointment and save it.  Make sure your Notice (nominally 15 minutes) is set the way you need.

I do this very frequently to add events to my own calendar.

This is about the best you can do.

Comment: Agree with John, i'm afraid that you cannot make the email shown as Calendar event directly.

Comment: I have given you an answer that works. You may wish to acknowledge the answer

Comment: Thank you! What's the correct practice here if the answer is as useful but does not perfectly solve the problem (through no fault of yours but rather the program's)? Should I mark it as answered or leave it open but upvote?

Comment: There is no automatic way to create an appointment the way you want. So you can mark the workaround as answer or upvote it . Either way it will stay for others to ser