# In Outlook, how would you schedule a reoccurring meeting for the Sunday following the first Wednesday of the month?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I want to create a reoccurring appointment that takes place on the Sunday following the first Wednesday of the month.  I will likely just create each one manually but was optimistic that someone might know of a way to use the reoccurring features in Outlook to 'get it right' for the next 12 months using the tool itself.

- October   8, 2023
- November  5, 2023
- December 10, 2023

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create Microsoft Outlook calendar invite from Microsoft Teams meeting link](https://superuser.com/questions/1812526/create-microsoft-outlook-calendar-invite-from-microsoft-teams-meeting-link)

Comment: this might help ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713266/excel-create-an-outlook-calendar-event#44436457

Comment: Is your issue how to program recurrence, how to program THIS SPECIFIC recurrence, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Setting up recurring meetings may not be exactly what you want. Because recurring meetings are regular intervals (daily/monthly/yearly). For Wednesdays and Sundays of the week, meeting requirements will not be met if they are not in the same month. For example, December 10, 2023

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.